# adding controller specific document eventlistener in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I am developing a web application for conducting the online quiz. I am using the mean stack for this. In  my online test controller, I have used many event listeners  such as

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
document.webkitIsFullScreen etc..
```

But my problem is this function still executing after moving to other controllers Because this is global eventLisners.

Can anyone suggest me best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the event listener when the scope is destroyed or as you put it 'after moving to other controllers':

```
$scope.$on('$destroy',function() {
   document.removeEventListener('visibilitychange',onchange);
});
```

Its always a good idea to handle the removal of event listeners when a component is destroyed, especially for large applications, as this can be a major cause of memory leak issues for single page applications.

Comment: Thanks bluetoft.
Is it a good practice to write this logic in the controller ? 
or can I use a directive or service for this ?

Comment: @kiranGopal I generally wire this sort of stuff up in the controller, but could see how you might easily write a service to handle it, if you are doing enough of this sort of thing.